# How to render a SkiaSharp.SKBitmap as HTML with Blazor?

Tags: html, blazor-webassembly, skiasharp

How do I render a SkiaSharp.SKBitmap as HTML with Blazor (in a WASM client)? Ofc I googled before asking here, but didn't find any information about that.

Comment: what do you mean by rendering a bitmap as html?

Comment: Create some HTML that will cause the bitmap to be properly rendered as image.